# Continuing index of paginated table after first page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have a paginated table like this:

[image]

[image]

But as you see, the index starts from `0` on the second page; it should continue continue at `11`.

Here's the code;

```
const tableDevices = this.state.pageOfDevices.map((device, index) => {
        return <TableRow key={device.id} selected={this.isSelected(index)}>
          <TableRowColumn>{index+1}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{device.id}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{device.description}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    });
```

So how can I achieve to track the index of all items rather than starting from 0 on the other page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what page you are on and how many items are displayed per page, you can easily adjust the index.

Below I have assumed the variables `currentPage` and `itemsPerPage`. Assume that `currentPage` starts from `0`.

```
const tableDevices = this.state.pageOfDevices.map((device, index) => {
  return <TableRow key={device.id} selected={this.isSelected(index)}>
      <TableRowColumn>{(currentPage*itemsPerPage) + index+1}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{device.id}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{device.description}</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
});
```

So assuming you display 10 items per page, your indexing would be:

- First page: `(currentPage*itemsPerPage) + index+1` = `(0*10) + index+1` = `index+1`.
- Second page: `(currentPage*itemsPerPage) + index+1` = `(1*10) + index+1` = `10 + index+1`.
- Third page: `(currentPage*itemsPerPage) + index+1` = `(2*10) + index+1` = `20 + index+1`.

...and so on.

---

Though it's probably better if you somehow modify the data in `pageOfDevices` to include a true index. Because then you could do:

```
const tableDevices = this.state.pageOfDevices.map((device, index) => {
  return <TableRow key={device.id} selected={this.isSelected(index)}>
      <TableRowColumn>{device.index}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{device.id}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{device.description}</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
});
```